# reselect selector with other selector as parameter doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reselect

I'm trying to use a reselect selector as an argument to another selector:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'


const productsSelector = state => {
  return state.get('searchResults').get('products')
}

export const getSelectedProduct = createSelector(
  productsSelector,
  (products) => {
    const selected = products.filter(product => product.shop.selected)
    return selected[0]
  }
)

export const getSelectedProductProduct = createSelector(
  getSelectedProduct,
  prod => {
    const x = prod ? prod.products ? prod.products.find(produc => produc.selected) : getSelectedProduct : {}
    if(prod) {
      console.log(prod)
      if ('prod', prod.products) {
        console.log(prod.products)
        if (prod.products.find(produ => produ.selected)) {
          console.log('sel prod', prod.products.find(produ => produ.selected))
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(x)
  }
)
```

`getSelectedProduct` is working and updating when it should update. However `getSelectedProductProduct` is not executing. What am I doing wrong?

They're used in a component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  region: state.get('map').get('region'),
  markers: state.get('searchResults').get('products'),
  selectedProduct: getSelectedProduct(state),
  selectedProductProduct: getSelectedProductProduct(state)
})
```

**action diff**

[image]

**redux state**

[image]

The redux action which causes the diff in the top image does not cause `getSelectedProductProduct` to execute. I don't think the component knows that its field changed. I'm investigating this further. Wondering if the field is too deeply nested for the component to register the change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `getSelectedProduct` filters `searchResults.products.shop` but the action is changing `searchResults.products.products[1].selected`. So `getSelectedProduct` returns the same value unchanged every time. That is why `getSelectedProductProduct` doesn't re-compute.

Comment: Thanks. The shape of my data is like `{shop: shopFields, products: productsArray}` and yes my `shop` is not changing from the action. My `products` are. But `getSelectedProduct` returns the whole `{shop: shopFields, products: productsArray}` object. I confirmed this and it returned `Object {shop: Object, products: Array(6)}`. This means that it is returning the `products` which my action acts on. Therefore the object that `getSelectedProducts` returns does change from the action.